# Customize beamer block style

Tags: beamer

I am using `Montpellier` theme with beamer, however the block style have no default background etc. I tried a few ways to make it look like the style of `Boadilla`, but I can't reproduce it good enough.

[image]

Being new to beamer, the search led me to customize it with `setbeamercolor`, but I am lost on how exactly specify color the way `Boadilla` did. Can you help?

```
\documentclass[c,compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}

%\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue!75!black}

\title{My title}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A Test}
    \begin{block}{definition}
        a test for block
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the contents of `beamerthemeBoadilla.sty` you will find:

```
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

Thus, `Boadilla` uses the `rose` color theme for the inner theme and the `dolphin` color theme for the outer theme. In your code you have `\usecolortheme{beaver}`, which is also an inner theme. You can simply change `beaver` to `rose`, or if you want something similar but different to `rose` you can customize your colors based on the contents of `beamercolorthemerose.sty`.